# Jenkins: Does SafeRestart plugin work while jenkins is running as a Tomcat service?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

Does SafeRestart plugin work while jenkins is running as a Tomcat service on windows machine? I am getting "http status 500" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No SafeRestart plugin doesn't work with Windows services ( this includes Tomcat or embeded winston server )